# VS Code PHP Format Single Attribute Per Line

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm trying to set VS Code to format the HTML part of the PHP file as
`signleAttributePerLine`. My current project settings:

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[PHP]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
  },
  "prettier.singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "intelephense.singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto",
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.semi": false,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "cSpell.words": ["gematriya", "roadmap", "WPAPI"]
}
```

Example: 
I want this:

```
<div class="d-flex gap-3 field-control flex-wrap">
  <?php
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($select_values as ['label' => $label, 'value' => $value]) :
    if ($counter >= 10) break;
  ?>
    <div class="small-button" data-post-type="<?= $post_type ?>" data-type="<?= esc_attr($type) ?>" role="button" data-value="<?= esc_attr($value) ?>">
      <?= $label ?>
    </div>
  <?php
    $counter++;
  endforeach;
  ?>
</div>
```

To turn into this (on save):

```
<div class="d-flex gap-3 field-control flex-wrap">
  <?php
  $counter = 0;
  foreach ($select_values as ['label' => $label, 'value' => $value]) :
    if ($counter >= 10) break;
  ?>
    <div 
      class="small-button"
      data-post-type="<?= $post_type ?>"
      data-type="<?= esc_attr($type) ?>"
      role="button"
      data-value="<?= esc_attr($value) ?>"
    >
      <?= $label ?>
    </div>
  <?php
    $counter++;
  endforeach;
  ?>
</div>
```

Note - I am happy with the current PHP part formatting, just want to update the HTML part.

Comment: i wondered same you. how to set "printWidth" on php?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the [Format HTML in PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rifi2k.format-html-in-php) extension.
2. Change the setting `HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` to `force-expand-multiline`:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",  // should be in your settings
```

3. Add this to your settings (`settings.json`):

```
"[php]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Now when you save a `.php` document the html inside it should be formatted according to the html formatting options you set in vscode.

[image: format HTML in PHP demo]

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. Does the job.

Comment: This did work for me, but how would this be done without format on save?